# Covariance of two spherical variables

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, elliptical-distribution

I have encountered a problem here. Suppose $x_1,x_2,x_3\in\mathbb{R}^p$ are three independent r.v. following $N(0,I_p)$, then I want to derive the value of
$$E\bigg\{\big(\frac{\beta^T(x_1-x_2)}{||x_1-x_2||_2}\big)^2\big(\frac{\beta^T(x_1-x_3)}{||x_1-x_3||_2}\big)^2\bigg\}$$
or equivalently, the covariance
$$cov\bigg\{\big(\frac{\beta^T(x_1-x_2)}{||x_1-x_2||_2}\big)^2,\big(\frac{\beta^T(x_1-x_3)}{||x_1-x_3||_2}\big)^2\bigg\}$$
where $\beta\in\mathbb{R}^p$ is an arbitrary vector satisfying $||\beta||_2 = 1$. $||\cdot||_2$ is Euclidean norm.

I guess the covariance is of the rate $O_p(p^{-2})$ but I don't know how to derive it.

Let $w_1=x_1-x_2, w_2 = x_1-x_3$, then we have
$$\begin{pmatrix}w_1\\
w_2\end{pmatrix} \sim N\bigg(0,\begin{pmatrix}2I_p&I_p\\
I_p&I_p\end{pmatrix}\bigg).$$
Then
$$E\bigg\{\big(\frac{\beta^Tw_1}{||w_1||_2}\big)^2\big(\frac{\beta^T(w_2)}{||w_2||_2}\big)^2\bigg\} = E_{w_2}E_{w_1|w_2}\bigg\{\big(\frac{\beta^Tw_1}{||w_1||_2}\big)^2\big(\frac{\beta^T(w_2)}{||w_2||_2}\big)^2|w_2\bigg\}.$$
I know that $w_1|w_2\sim N(w_2,I_p)$, but I don't know the consequent results.

Comment: Could you please provide the source of this problem? Or the background of it?

Comment: @Zhanxiong It's from my current work on elliptical-distributed data. This problem is a minor part I want to compute in the theoretical result.